# How to seal gap between brick, stucco and framing?

Tags: framing, stucco, seal

I’m replacing windows and found a substantial gap between the brick and stucco. The old windows had been leaking for a while and I suspect that this was part of the issue.

How should I deal with this before installing the new windows?

[image: click for photo]

Comment: Was there anything covering that up before?

Comment: With no context, it's hard to tell how "substantial" that gap is. Is it 1", 3", 1/2"? Give us some dimensions to work with...

Comment: @FreeMan I mean, we could assume those bricks are standard size, so about 2-1/2" tall, making the gap between brick and wood about 2-1/4-ish.

Comment: Sorry, @Huesmann. I'm unable to see images at the moment, so I had no picture to work from...